# iOS: How to flip image based on current orientation?

Tags: ios, uiimage, orientation

I am trying to check the current orientation of an image and flip it to the opposite of what it currently is.

This code works if I only have 1 element on my screen, but as soon as i increase the array its a 50/50 chance of getting the orientation right.

```
-(IBAction)flipBtn:(id)sender
{

    UIImage* flippedImage;
    if(flipBtn.tag==FLIP_BUTTON_TAG)
    {
        UIImage* sourceImage1 = self.outletImageView.image;
        flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage1.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
        flipBtn.tag = FLIP_VUTTON_TAG2;

    }else{
        UIImage* sourceImage1 = self.outletImageView.image;
        flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage1.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
        flipBtn.tag = FLIP_BUTTON_TAG;

    }
     NSInteger index1 = [imgViewArray indexOfObject:self.outletImageView];
    [imgViewArray removeObject:self.outletImageView];
    self.outletImageView.image = flippedImage;
    [imgViewArray insertObject:self.outletImageView atIndex:index1];

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Instead of**: `[imgViewArray removeObject:self.outletImageView];`

**Write:** `[imgViewArray removeObjectAtIndex:index1];`

And afterwards you need to check `flippedImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp` to see if it's inverted or not and make the appropriate change.

You can verify which orientation the picture has by accessing the info dictionary `[info objectForKey:@"Orientation"]`

Here is a method that will return the new desired orientation based on your previous check (you'd pass `flippedImage.imageOrientation` as the argument):

```
- (UIImageOrientation)orientation:(int)orientation
{
    UIImageOrientation newOrientation;
    switch (orientation)
    {
        case 1:
            newOrientation = UIImageOrientationUp;
            break;
        case 2:
            newOrientation = UIImageOrientationUpMirrored;
            break;

    }  
    return newOrientation;  
}
```

Comment: this doesn't address the issue, it still doesn't detect what the current orientation is and then mirror it. this is working in the exact same manner as before